# REST API standard status codes

Tags: php, api

I Created a Rest Api for an ios app with a slim framework.
For identifing Post requests I created my own set of status codes.
As seen below for error responses.

```
{"status":"Incorrect Pin","code":3}
{"status":"server error","code":4}
```

But our app developer said that that does not match international standards.
He suggested something like the following.

```
{"status":"Incorrect Pin","code":404}
 {"status":"servererror","code":404}
```

I know  200,404, are basic http status code but what are the international standards for such a code?
Can anyone explain this to me?

Answer (score 4):

I think you are looking for below status code

```
                    100 => 'Continue',  
                    101 => 'Switching Protocols',  
                    200 => 'OK',
                    201 => 'Created',  
                    202 => 'Accepted',  
                    203 => 'Non-Authoritative Information',  
                    204 => 'No Content',  
                    205 => 'Reset Content',  
                    206 => 'Partial Content',  
                    300 => 'Multiple Choices',  
                    301 => 'Moved Permanently',  
                    302 => 'Found',  
                    303 => 'See Other',  
                    304 => 'Not Modified',  
                    305 => 'Use Proxy',  
                    306 => '(Unused)',  
                    307 => 'Temporary Redirect',  
                    400 => 'Bad Request',  
                    401 => 'Unauthorized',  
                    402 => 'Payment Required',  
                    403 => 'Forbidden',  
                    404 => 'Not Found',  
                    405 => 'Method Not Allowed',  
                    406 => 'Not Acceptable',  
                    407 => 'Proxy Authentication Required',  
                    408 => 'Request Timeout',  
                    409 => 'Conflict',  
                    410 => 'Gone',  
                    411 => 'Length Required',  
                    412 => 'Precondition Failed',  
                    413 => 'Request Entity Too Large',  
                    414 => 'Request-URI Too Long',  
                    415 => 'Unsupported Media Type',  
                    416 => 'Requested Range Not Satisfiable',  
                    417 => 'Expectation Failed',
                    426 => 'Upgrade required'  
                    500 => 'Internal Server Error',  
                    501 => 'Not Implemented',  
                    502 => 'Bad Gateway',  
                    503 => 'Service Unavailable',  
                    504 => 'Gateway Timeout',  
                    505 => 'HTTP Version Not Supported');
```

I have taken from [REST API](http://www.9lessons.info/2012/05/create-restful-services-api-in-php.html)

Edit : Added status code `426 => Upgrade Required` thanks @Nisse Engström

```
   Also you can look all the here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes
```

Comment: Your list is missing status code [`426 - Upgrade Required`](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#page-49).